# Weakening of magnet effect

Tags: magnetic-fields

Does the presence of a neodymium magnet around (or in the proximity) of the iron (no connection and At a distance of 1 millimeter ) lead to the gradual weakening of magnet effect?
What if it connects?

Answer (score 0):

Distance of 1mm? If no other significant stopping force acts, nothing can stop attraction ;;neodymium magnet will definitely "connect" to iron rod. Assuming they are kept at a distance or are held back from "connecting" the magnet will align domains and cause the iron itself to become a temporary magnet. And as of sticking it to the rod,the rod will not affect the strength of magnet in anyway and actually that is the way bar magnets or horseshoe have to be ideally stored ( I don't know if its applicable to neodymium). So I think it totally does not matter.